# macos monterey doesn't allow dock to move to external display

Tags: display, dock, monterey

I have added an external LG display using builtin type c port on macbook m1 pro. I am trying to move the dock to secondary screen and use macbook display as extended one. but it doesn't allow me to move dock from macbook display to LS monitor display.

either of below will work for me.

- keep dock on both the screens
- move dock to external display

[image]
I tried to move the white bar from one display to other, white bar only change extended display to main display but dock remains on the macbook display.

Comment: Can't test this for Monterey, but you've never been able to put the Dock at the bottom of the top screen when stacked vertically. There's nowhere for your cursor to hit easily, like you can when it's at the edge of your total display..

Comment: i couldn't put the dock on the bottom of top screen, when stacked vertically.

Comment: That's how it's always been.

Comment: The "white bar" is the menu bar, not the Dock.